# exploded-aar breakpoints show no executable code found at line x

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I've an android app.  I'm importing an aar file in libs folder of this android project.

I've this defined in my build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile(name: 'MyFile', ext: 'aar')
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile files('build/intermediates/exploded-aar/MyFile/classes.jar')
    compile files('build/intermediates/exploded-aar/MyFile/libs/mycore.jar')
}
```

When I try to debug exploded aar for mycore.jar, i get error "no executible code found at line xx".  I've the correct source attached to these jars.  I'm able to successfully debug classes.jar.  I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong. I've been trying to fix this for a day now.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling proguard while in debug mode.Your gradle file should look something like this

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
    }
    debug {
        debuggable true
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
    }
}
```

If the above does't work then switch to Dalvik when compiling in a device rather than ART.Also try rebuilding the project and also try `File --> Invalidate Cache/Restart`

Comment: I'm building it as assembleDebug.  I've minifyEnabled false in any case in release.  i dont have proguard running in debug buildTypes.  I will try debuggable true now.  I will comment to this if that works. thanks.

Comment: Okay are you compiling on device with ART?If yes then try compiling with Dalvik

Comment: I'm not seeing the option to change runtime on my phone (In developer options) :(

Comment: I've already tried doing invalidate cache/restart like 20 times.  It did not help.

Answer (score 0):

I think "make"(Ctrl + F9) or "compile"  the project again.